# How to set offset in kafkalistener

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I'm trying to consume data from kafka server, I'm using `@Kafkalistener` annotation.

The problem is that I'm getting all the messages every time I restart my application.
How do I save the last consumed offset in my application and use it to consume next messages?

Answer (score 3):

This tutorial has the answer:
https://www.codenotfound.com/spring-kafka-boot-example.html

> The kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset property needs to be set to
>   'earliest' which ensures the new consumer group will get the message
>   sent in case the container started after the send was completed.

So you should set it to latest as per your requirement